# Question related to date and join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to combine three different tables.
Table 1 and 2 got a row with the same ID,which in this case is the product_id, and the same goes for table 2 and 3. I'm using date as a condition when I'm sending the query, where I'm only supposed to get the results that fit inside the given frame. Here's my code:

```
select order.orderDate, orderLine.order_id, product.product_id, product.name
from order, product
inner join orderLine
on product.product_id = orderLine.product_id
where order.orderDate between  '2009-09-01' and '2009-09-30' ;
```

When I use this, I only get one date, contained in the order-table. I also get info from rows that don't fit the date given.

I'm very sorry if this is nothing but confusing. My english isn't very good, so having a hard time making this understandable. Also, please let me know if you need more information.   New to both this site and SQL.

Comment: Shouldn't be `between date '2009-09-01' and date '2009-09-30'`?

Comment: @Joel No, it should not.

Comment: @Adrian, that's what happens when you get used to PL/SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try joining all three tables:

```
select o.orderDate, ol.order_id, p.product_id, p.name
from order as o 
inner join orderLine as ol
   on ol.order_id = o.order_id
inner join  product as p on o
   on p.product_id = ol.product_id
where o.orderDate between  '2009-09-01' and '2009-09-30' ;
```

Comment: That might just be it. Unfortunately, I can't test it right now as I only got access at my uni. But will try it out first thing in the morning! Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: Your problem is you mixed implict and explict syntax and the implicit syntax is a cross join. There is no circumstance where implict syntax should be used. Do not ever write code using it again as it a very bad SQl antipattern. Accidental cross joins like this are part of why it is an extremely poor programming technique to use these joins that were replaced 20 years years ago with a better technique.

Answer (score 0):

While I think the missing join clause (as per @p.campbell's answer) will solve your "too many rows returned" problem, I'm wondering if whether there is a further "not enough rows returned" problem with your date representation e.g.

```
where order.orderDate between '2009-09-01' and '2009-09-30'
```

The intention is presumably to return orders for September 2009 but would omit one where `orderDate = '2009-09-01 12:00:00'`.

Your code implies you are using what the literature calls closed-closed representation of periods, where the end date is included in the period. However, the recommendation is use closed-open representation (also known as half open intervals) where the end date is not included in the period.

Thus, using closed-open representation, the same predicate (i.e. all September 2009 orders) would be:

```
where order.orderDate >= '2009-09-01' 
      and order.orderDate < '2009-10-01'
```

For more details, see [Snodgrass, Richard T. (1999). Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf), chapter 4 Periods.